# Is there a way to check if any part of a data layer in google maps is within the bounds of the map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a list of geojson polygons that i am showing on my map, i am trying to determine, based on the current bounds of the map, if any part of the polygon is on the map. Any ideas as far as functions in the api to determine this?

I have tried the bounds.contains() method but it looks like that needs a specific point rather than an area.

Comment: "any part of the Polygon" ... you can test each point of a Polygon, if "any" point is contained, then you can deduce that a "part" of the Polygon is within the bounds.

Comment: The problem that i am running into is that the polygons are fairly large, so testing just the perimeter points won't quite be enough.

Comment: Well... you should demonstrate what you have tried and why it fails. The fact that a Polygon is large doesn't make any difference IMO.

Answer (score -3):

Eric, I think you can get a center point of each polygon and set marker to it. So you can use it to represent a polygon.

Comment: How would one do that?  What are the steps?